# Javascript switch-case: using individual methods to evaluate a case statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is it possible to use functions that accept the single switch value and return a boolean to test individual case statements?

If not, is there a more efficient (for speed or readability) way to run similar tests other than using if statements?

Example below for illustration.

In the code below: 
IsInt(value) is a function that returns true or false if the value is an integer
isMultipleOfThree(value) is a function that returns true or false if the value is a multiple of three.

```
var switchVal = "9";

switch( switchVal ){
  case(isMultipleOfThree):
    console.log(switchVal + ' is a multiple of three.');

  case(isInt):
    console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer.');
    break;

  default:
    console.log(switchVal + ' is not an integer or a multiple of three.');
 }
```

Comment: This syntax won't work as you're intending, regardless of the functions in the `case()` portions. Without a break on your first `case`, your second case will always get hit if the first is true. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/f8Ljagae/

Comment: i used nested ternary statements to do this once

Comment: Thanks @Santi - I fixed it to be consistent as an illustration.

Comment: @craignewkirk Added another alternative to my answer as well using a C approach and flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could use `switch(true) {}` to do something similar:

```
var switchVal = "9";

switch( true ){
  case isInt(switchVal):
    console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer.');

  case isMultipleOfThree(switchVal):
    console.log(switchVal + ' is a multiple of three.');
    break;

  default:
    console.log(switchVal + ' is not an integer or a multiple of three.');
 }
```

If you're trying to execute *all* passing cases, you could write a function that does that:

```
function last(arr) {
  return arr[arr.length - 1];
}

function allCases(value, ...cases) {
  let defaultCase;
  let hasPassedAny = false;
  if(typeof last(cases) === "function") {
    defaultCase = last(cases);
    cases = cases.slice(0, -1);
  }
  cases.forEach(([predicate, resultFn]) => {
    if(predicate(value)) {
      hasPassedAny = true;
      resultFn(value);
    }
  });
  if(defaultCase && !hasPassedAny) {
    defaultCase(value);
  }
}

allCases(switchVal,
  [isInt, (v) => {
    console.log(`${v} is an integer`);
  }],
  [isMultipleOfThree, (v) => {
    console.log(`${v} is a multiple of three`);
  }],
  (v) => {
    console.log(`${v} is not an integer or a multiple of three.`);
  }
);
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, if the value is an integer, but **not** a multiple of three, the console in your example will still print "7 is an integer. 7 is a multiple of three." Example: https://jsfiddle.net/f8Ljagae/1/

Comment: @Santi So it should execute *all* of the cases that are true?

Comment: I mean I think it's quite obvious that passing a number like 7 shouldn't log "7 is a multiple of three"...

Comment: If you forget a break then script will run from the case where criteria is met, and will run the case after that regardless if criteria was met. This is why is it saying 7 is a multiple of three.

Comment: @Santi Right. Your code didn't have a `break` after the first case so it falls through. I'm trying to understand what you expect it to do if `9` is passed.

Comment: I believe you're confusing me with @craignewkirk. I only commented to point out this issue, craignewkirk is the one who posted the question. I posted a similar comment on the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about an `if else if`?

```
var switchVal = "9";

if(isInt(switchVal)){
    console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer.');
}else if(isMultipleOfThree(switchVal)){
    console.log(switchVal + ' is a multiple of three.');
}else{
    console.log(switchVal + ' is not an integer or a multiple of three.');
}
```

However, this doesn't solve the issue where if it is 9, it will exit and only print 9 is an integer. You can separate them into different in blocks.

```
var switchVal = "9";

if(isInt(switchVal)){
    console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer.');
if(isMultipleOfThree(switchVal)){
    console.log(switchVal + ' is a multiple of three.');
if(!isInt(switchVal) && !isMultipleOfThree(switchVal))
    console.log(switchVal + ' is not an integer or a multiple of three.');
}
```

But this can get messy when you add more and more tests. This of course is assuming you have two functions `isInt` and `isMultipleOfThree` that return true or false.

Another weird alternative taking a C approach with flags.

```
function isInt(s){
    if (!isNaN(s))
    return 1; //0001
  return 0;
}

function isMultipleOfThree(s){
    var int = parseInt(s);
    if(int % 3 === 0)
    return 2; //0010
  return 0;
}

function isSevem(s){
 var int = parseInt(s);
    if(int === 7)
    return 4; // 0100
  return 0;
}

var switchVal = "7";
console.log(7 % 3 === 0);
var result = isSevem(switchVal) + isMultipleOfThree(switchVal) + isInt(switchVal);
switch( result ){
  case 1: // 0001
    console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer.');
        break;
  case 2: // 0010
    console.log(switchVal + ' is a multiple of three.');
    break;
  case 3: // 0011
    console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer and a multiple of three.');
    break;
  case 4: // 0100
    console.log(switchVale + ' is the number seven.');
    break;
  case 5: // 0101
     console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer and is the number seven.');
     break;
  case 6: // 0110
    console.log(switchVal + ' is a multiple of three and is the number seven.');
    break;
  case 7: // 0111
    console.log(switchVal + ' is an integer and is a multiple of three and is the number seven.');
    break;

  default:
    console.log(switchVal + ' is not an integer or a multiple of three.');
    break;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to avoid since I've got several tests.  I know I can do this with if statements, it just seems more readable with a switch statement.  Plus switch statements generally have performance benefits at scale.

Comment: @craignewkirk you are right. I made the mistake in assuming all your switches had `breaks;`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional solution, Loaf!  I thought about using bit flags as well, but was looking for something more readable.  Ultimately using 'true' in the switch test was the most readable solution for my situation.